# multiplication of functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been multiplying functions for ages but I never really stopped and considered why I could multiply functions and have it "just work." Here's an example

Say $f(1) = 9, g(1) = 7$. Then $(f(1)-g(1))^2 = (9-7)^2=2^2=4$.

We could also do $(f-g)^2 = f^2-2fg+g^2$, and so $f^2(1)-2f(1)g(1)+g^2(1)=81-126+49=4$.

Was this ever explained in grade school??

edit 1: Wait actually it makes sense. actually I think the larger question is why $(x+y)^2 = x^2+2xy+y^2$

Comment: It works because functions are just your regular ol' numbers when you put something into it (e.g. $1$ in your case), so the algebra works out.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 yes that's what I realized.

Comment: For the question in your edit: it's because multiplication distributes over addition. Look up the "distributive property" if you want more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question, when I am answering this, is

> Why is $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$?

One way is to straight away dive into algebra by expanding the product $(x+y)(x+y)$, which I believe is not what you're looking for.

(The image I have uses $a$ and $b$ instead of $x$ and $y$, so I will also use them hereafter.)

Another way is to interpret this geometrically. What does $a^2$ mean? The area of a square with side length $a$. Similarly, what does $ab$ mean?  The area of a rectangle with sides $a$ and $b$. With all this in the hand, let's look at the diagram.

[image]

So we have a square of side length $(a+b)$ (and consequently the area of this is equal to $(a+b)^2$). Now, as you are seeing, we divide the sides into lengths $a$ and $b$. From the figure, it is evident that you get
$$\color{gray}{(a+b)^2}=\color{yellow}{a^2}+2\color{lime}{ab}+\color{cyan}{b^2}$$
(As you might have noticed, I have colour coded these areas.)

Hopefully that makes sense. Ask anything if not clear :)